# Why WaitForMultipleObjectsEx acquires mutex during APC?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, mutex, apc, waitformultipleobjects

I have 5 threads (on a multicore system) that simultaneously wait for:

1. A mutex M to be acquired
2. An event E to be signaled

I'm using `WaitForMultipleObjectsEx(..., TRUE, INFINITE, TRUE)` since the threads use APCs.
Note that the APCs do *not* use/touch/alter/observe the mutex or the event in any way.

I'm using Visual Studio along with [Process Hacker](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/) to debug, and I'm witnessing a strange phenomenon:
Frequently, the thread that is *supposed* to run (call it thread A) is still waiting on the two objects.

I say "supposed to run" because:

1. I have verified many times (including via Process Hacker) that the E is indeed in a signaled state
2. No other thread has acquired ownership of M.  In fact, *3* other threads are *also* waiting to acquire M.

Nevertheless, according to Process Hacker (which uses [`NtQueryMutant` to retrieve the count](http://forum.sysinternals.com/check-mutant-state-without-altering-its-state_topic27466.html)), *during such scenarios*, M has an absurdly low "Count" value, such as -618.

Of course, I'm not forgetting to call `ReleaseMutex` (yes, I'm checking the return value too); indeed, once someone later acquires the mutex, the Count increases back up.

So this begs the question: if 3 of the 4 other threads are sleeping, what is the last thread (B) doing?

The answer is that B is **executing an APC** inside the `WaitForMultipleObjectsEx` call.
*No matter how far I "step" through B* in Visual Studio (even all the way back up `RtlDispatchAPC`), **none** of the other threads wake up.
It is only *after* that APC has finished executing that any thread wakes up!

I find this quite bizarre, [`WaitForMultipleObjectEx`'s documentation says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687028.aspx):

> When `bWaitAll` is `TRUE`, the function's wait operation is completed only when the states of all objects have been set to signaled. **The function does not modify the states of the specified objects until the states of all objects have been set to signaled.** For example, a mutex can be signaled, but **the thread does not get ownership** until the states of the other objects are also set to signaled. In the meantime, some other thread may get ownership of the mutex, thereby setting its state to nonsignaled.

Is the documentation wrong, or is this a mistake on my part?

Why does `WaitForMultipleObjectsEx` acquire the mutex during the execution of an APC, even though it *knows* it will never acquire the mutex anyway (because executing an APC implies it will return `WAIT_IO_COMPLETE`, never acquiring the mutex)?

Comment: The large negative count on the mutex implies that the same thread has acquired it multiple times, probably in some recursive fashion.  Why might this happen?  Do your APCs do alertable waits?

Comment: @arx: That's the funny thing -- my APCs *don't* do alertable waits. The maximum nesting of APC's is 1. (I've verified this both in the code and inside Process Hacker.)

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment so I use answer...

You don't show any code but shouldn't the APC trigger the WaitForMultipleObjectsEx return with WAIT_IO_COMPLETION code in the thread that is running??